# Group rows with preceeded by 0 in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a requirment to group rows preceeding by 0 in column A and sum up the values in column B. For rows that are not prceeded by 0, print the same in output. How can i acheive this using pandas dataframe. I have given sample grouping with expected output in the attached screenshot. even if there are rows 20 preceding rows it should group

[image]

Reproducible input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Column A': [0,0,1,1,1,0,-1,-1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,-1],
                   'Column B': [5,3,4,2,1,3,7,5,10,2,3,4,5,5,5,5,5]
                  })
```

Comment: Hi Please post your code as well as your desired output. Pictures are to be used sparesly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can use a reverse [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) to form a group, then compute a [`groupby.transform('sum')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) and [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) the output:

```
group = df.loc[::-1, 'Column A'].ne(0).cumsum()[::-1]
m = group.duplicated(keep='last')

out = df.join(df.groupby(group, as_index=False).transform('sum')
                .add_suffix(' output').mask(m))
```

Output:

```
    Column A  Column B  Column A output  Column B output
0          0         5              NaN              NaN
1          0         3              NaN              NaN
2          1         4              1.0             12.0
3          1         2              1.0              2.0
4          1         1              1.0              1.0
5          0         3              NaN              NaN
6         -1         7             -1.0             10.0
7         -1         5             -1.0              5.0
8          0        10              NaN              NaN
9          0         2              NaN              NaN
10         0         3              NaN              NaN
11         1         4              1.0             19.0
12         0         5              NaN              NaN
13         0         5              NaN              NaN
14         0         5              NaN              NaN
15         0         5              NaN              NaN
16        -1         5             -1.0             25.0
```

Alternatively, if you just want the sum of B as output:

```
group = df.loc[::-1, 'Column A'].ne(0).cumsum()[::-1]
m = group.duplicated(keep='last')

df.loc[~m, 'out'] = df.groupby(group)['Column B'].transform('sum')
```

Or, slightly more efficient variant:

```
group = df.loc[::-1, 'Column A'].ne(0).cumsum()[::-1]
m = group.duplicated(keep='last')

df.loc[~m, 'out'] = df.groupby(group, sort=False)['Column B'].sum().to_numpy()
```

Output:

```
    Column A  Column B   out
0          0         5   NaN
1          0         3   NaN
2          1         4  12.0
3          1         2   2.0
4          1         1   1.0
5          0         3   NaN
6         -1         7  10.0
7         -1         5   5.0
8          0        10   NaN
9          0         2   NaN
10         0         3   NaN
11         1         4  19.0
12         0         5   NaN
13         0         5   NaN
14         0         5   NaN
15         0         5   NaN
16        -1         5  25.0
```